# Merging PHP code if statement. Magento Attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product

I am trying to merge these 2 line of code for an if statement. The purpose is to hide the attribute if Code1 is blank. Each one reports correct but when place together the code give errors. Thanks for the hint :)

Code1

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('tempi_consegna') != '')  ?>
```

Code2

```
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Consegna:') ?>
    <span>
        <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('tempi_consegna') ?>
    </span>
</p>
```

They should be living friendly in magento product availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as following:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('tempi_consegna') != ''):  ?>
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Consegna:') ?>
    <span>
        <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('tempi_consegna') ?>
    </span>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```